# Can I bundle and migrate a standalone Aurelia App that can run on apache server without node.js?

Tags: wordpress, apache, aurelia

First of I am new to Aurelia and has just completed a real world project on my development server which I like to run concurrently with WordPress which needs PHP. Back in the days with angular 1.x I used to gulp all the angular dependencies and scripts into a single file and transfer it to the server, which I thought would be the case with Aurelia too but looks like it is more complex in this matter. So please if any one has come around to this problem, any help would be appericated like how can I port Aurelia project to apache server without serving it through node. Or is it possible to run node and apache on same server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to run Node to serve your application. Any web server - such as Apache - will do. You only need to bundle your application and upload the files to your server.

If your project was created using the CLI, the application is bundled automatically every time you run `au run` (or `au build`), so you can simply upload the `scripts` directory and the `index.html` file. This is the minimum; you may need to upload also CSS, images or fonts, depending on your app.

If your project is based on one of the skeletons, you can bundle your app by running `gulp bundle`, then upload the `dist`directory, the `jspm_packages` directory, the `config.js` file and the `index.html` file, plus anny other asset (CSS, images, etc.) you may need.

Comment: Thank you @manuel-guilbault. But I've tried this already. I tired to build the project with au CLI like au build --env prod then I copy the scripts and index.html to a new directory in my local server I get error like this
'XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/aureliafp/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?filter[name]=home-page. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.' I do not know what is causing this. So please help me out if you have ran into this error before.

Comment: This looks like a CORS issue. If your JS app makes HTTP calls (using XMLHttpRequest directly or through a wrapper like jQuery's ajax method) to a web service that is not on the same domain, this web service must be CORS-enabled.
I suggest to have a look at MDN's doc on the subject:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thank you once again. I have fixed the issue with CORS and had my app running on apache server. Thank you for your suggestions.